# Write function that should return true if the target integer can be obtained by placing addition or subtraction operations in the list

Tags: python, algorithm

Example :

```
f(5, [5, 2]) = false. There's no way to add or subtract 5 and 2 to get 5.

f(13, [3, 9, 3, 2]) = true. 3 + 9 + 3 - 2 = 13.

f(0, []) = true

f(1, []) = false
```

I tried below code but still, at some point, it is breaking. Do you guys suggest any simple or efficient solution?

```
def getWays(magic_number, numbers):
    if( util(numbers, 0, magic_number) > 0 ):
        return True

    return False

def util(numbers, i, magic_number):

    n = len(numbers)

    if( i >= len(numbers) and magic_number != 0 ):
        return 0

    if (magic_number == 0):
        return 1

    return util(numbers, i + 1, magic_number) + util(numbers, i + 1, magic_number - numbers[i]) + util(numbers, i + 1, magic_number + numbers[i])

if(getWays(13, [3, 9, 3, 2])):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

Note: It is not any homework or assignment. I was just trying it for practice.

Comment: "at some point, it is breaking". can you point out **where**?

Comment: getWays(5, [5, 2]), it should return false, but it returns True.

Comment: Could you describe the algorithm that you tried to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue with your code:

- When you say `f(5, [5, 2]) = false. There's no way to add or subtract 5 and 2 to get 5.`. But there **is**. How: `magic_number - numbers[0] == 0`. **That's exactly what is happening** because you have written `util(numbers, i + 1, magic_number)` in your code. Which ignores *ith* element (magic_number[i]) it neither adds it nor subtracts it while increasing *i* by 1.

So, I'm assuming that you want to consider **all** the elements in the array while *adding* or *subtracting*.

- Also, when you do `return 1 if (magic_number == 0)` you do not check **if the whole list is traversed or not**.

So IMHO you can do something like this perhaps:

```
def getWays(magic_number, numbers):
    if (util(numbers, 0, magic_number) > 0):
        return True
    return False


def util(numbers, i, magic_number):
    n = len(numbers)

    if i == n and magic_number != 0:
        return 0

    if magic_number == 0 and i == n:
        return 1

    return 1 if 1 in (util(numbers, i + 1, magic_number - numbers[i]), util(numbers, i + 1, magic_number + numbers[i])) else 0


if (getWays(13, [3, 9, 3, 2])):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")

if (getWays(5, [5, 2])):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")


    # True
    # False
```

Comment: Thank you @BlackBeard, You caught the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following recursive function:

```
from operator import add, sub
def getWays(target, operands):
    if not operands:
        return target == 0
    *remaining, operand = operands
    return any(getWays(operator(target, operand), remaining) for operator in (add, sub))
```

so that:

```
print(getWays(5, [5, 2]))
print(getWays(13, [3, 9, 3, 2]))
print(getWays(0, []))
print(getWays(1, []))
```

would output:

```
False
True
True
False
```

Comment: Awesome. You did nice job here.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

It might be solved with dynamic programming.

To make data suitable for subset sum formulation, one could make a list of source data together with negated data elements and provide checking that only one element from pair (x,-x) takes part in sum formation (for example, using binary masks).

+limit for minimal  number of used elements = 2